# Ubuntu Single Sign-on Account - Sign in button unclickable - Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, lubuntu, single-sign-on

I have discovered a new feature called Livepatch that keeps patching system between restarts. I am using Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. I went to the sign in button, and the "Choose an account" dialog appeared saying "To continue you need an Ubuntu Single Sign-on Account". I tried to press Sign in, but the button is disabled so it means that I can't sign in.

In my system, is there some packages related to Ubuntu Single Sign-on missing? Or is there something else wrong with it?

I am honestly running dual boot system in a 40GB Hard drive (Windows XP 30GB used for gaming and coding, Lubuntu 18.04 10GB used for other work). I am connected to WiFi.

Comment: Before you can "Sing in", you need to create an account. For more info, visit https://www.ubuntu.com/server/livepatch.

Comment: I have followed the steps on the link provided, but I think that the snap package named canonical-livepatch is only for 64-bit systems. I am on 32-bit, because Athlon XP 1500+ doesn't have 64-bit so I have to wait for 32-bit.

Comment: Indeed, according to the [System Requirements paragraph](https://assets.ubuntu.com/v1/ac3aa269-DS_Canonical_Livepatch_Service_screen-AW_08.17.pdf), live patch is only available for 64bit systems.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but why can't they make it for 32-bit?

Comment: Live patch is intended for system that run 24/7, most of which are 64 bit. More importantly, how useful would it be in your particular case, on a dual boot system that would be rebooted every few days, if not more often? I'd say, not at all.

Comment: So this live patch is only for servers and all 24/7 64-bit systems. Thanks for the info. I will not turn that live patch on.